# Python 3 write encrypted string of bytes to file

Tags: python-3.x, file, byte, aes

I encrypt string:

```
def encrypt(self, message):
    obj = AES.new('This is a key123'.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456'.encode("utf8"))
    encrypted = obj.encrypt(message.encode("utf8"))
    return encrypted
```

How can I store encrypted in a file and read to decrypt using:

```
def decrypt(self, encrypted):
    obj = AES.new('This is a key123'.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456'.encode("utf8"))
    decrypted=obj.decrypt(encrypted)
    return decrypted
```

Comment: A ciphertext consists simply of binary data. Are you asking how binary data should be stored/loaded? Or is it about encrypting large files in chunks?

Answer (score 0):

THe library "pycryptodome" has a full running example for AES encryption to a file and vice versa.

I know that the example runs another mode and stores additional data but that might be helpfull to you as the usage of a static IV is UNSECURE: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/examples.html

*The following code generates a new AES128 key and encrypts a piece of data into a file. We use the EAX mode because it allows the receiver to detect any unauthorized modification (similarly, we could have used other authenticated encryption modes like GCM, CCM or SIV).*

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)

file_out = open("encrypted.bin", "wb")
[ file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ]
file_out.close()
```

*At the other end, the receiver can securely load the piece of data back (if they know the key!). Note that the code generates a ValueError exception when tampering is detected.*

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

file_in = open("encrypted.bin", "rb")
nonce, tag, ciphertext = [ file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 16, -1) ]

# let's assume that the key is somehow available again
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
```